# How do I run the iPad simulator to test a website on my mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, xcode

I've developed a web app which is having some weird issues on iOS safari on my iPad.

I've never developed an iOS app, although I am a developer (c#) and have downloaded the latest xcode dev tools (just never got round to it).

Is there an easy way to just get the iPad sim up and start browsing the web on it on my mac?

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Install XCode, then the simulator is located at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
Once it's running, go to `Hardware` -> `Device`, then pick the iOS version and device.  It will boot up, then you can start Safari.

Update: XCode.app is now a package rather than a folder. In Finder, option/right click on XCode.app and select 'Show Package Contents', then follow the path down from there.

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of Xcode it can be found here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
```

Answer (score 2):

In  Xcode 6.1.1 (Yosemite & Mavericks) it can be found here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS Simulator
```

Comment: Hit `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `G` in `Finder` and paste the above address without the '/iOS Simulator' part to quickly go there

Answer (score 1):

On OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and xcode 7.0.1, the simulator is located at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```